# curl download file

Tags: curl

i have a url that when run from browser it starts download a file (ebup or pdf)
Because the url contains the uername and password i can not give my client this url so
i have to create a file to my server download.php that will download the file using curl.

Lets say the url is www.myebookspartner.com/username/ebooks/password/1234/ebookid/12

When i try to call this url with curl the download its not start (if i run form browser the downlaod starts immediately )

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);        
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);               
 $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);  
 $info=curl_getinfo($ch);           
 curl_close ($ch);
```

The curl_getinfo returns

```
{
  ["url"]=the url"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(35) "application/epub+zip; charset=utf-8"
  ["http_code"]=>;
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(861)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(318)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(5,622246)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0,000764)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0,056946)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(4,8E-5)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(510415)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(5,622168)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
}
```

What to do in order to force downloan the file from my file using curl

Thanks

Comment: `curl` is not intended to force browser to download file. Search in SO, there are a number of questions asking about forcing the browser to download the file, using `header()`

Comment: correct me if i am wrong but in the case of header i have to know the filename and in my case the filename is unknow when i make the call